# akka stream ActorSubscriber does not work with remote actors

Tags: stream, akka

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M2/scala/stream-integrations.html says:

"ActorPublisher and ActorSubscriber cannot be used with remote actors, because if signals of the Reactive Streams protocol (e.g. request) are lost the the stream may deadlock."

Does this mean akka stream is not location transparent? How do I use akka stream to design a backpressure-aware client-server system where client and server are on different machines?

I must have misunderstood something. Thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are strictly a **local** facility at this time. 
You can connect it to an TCP sink/source and it will apply back-pressure using TCP as well though (that's what Akka Http does).

Answer (score 2):

> How do I use akka stream to design a backpressure-aware client-server system where client and server are on different machines?

Check out [streams in Artery](http://blog.akka.io/artery/2016/12/02/streams-in-artery) (Dec. 2016, so 18 months later):

> [The new remoting implementation for actor messages was released in Akka 2.4.11 two months ago.](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/remoting-artery.html?_ga=1.40322338.1200191844.1474216026)
>   Artery is the code name for it. It’s a drop-in replacement to the old remoting in many cases, but the implementation is completely new and it comes with many important improvements.

(Remoting enables Actor systems on different hosts or JVMs to communicate with each other)

Regarding back-pressure, this is not a complete solution, but it can help:

> What about back-pressure? Akka Streams is all about back-pressure but actor messaging is fire-and-forget without any back-pressure. How is that handled in this design?
>
> We can’t magically add back-pressure to actor messaging. That must still be handled on the application level using techniques for message flow control, such as acknowledgments, work-pulling, throttling.
>
> When a message is sent to a remote destination it’s added to a queue that the first stage, called `SendQueue`, is processing. This queue is bounded and if it overflows the messages will be dropped, which is in line with the actor messaging at-most-once delivery nature. Large amount of messages should not be sent without application level flow control. For example, if serialization of messages is slow and can’t keep up with the send rate this queue will overflow.
>
> Aeron will propagate back-pressure from the receiving node to the sending node, i.e. the `AeronSink` in the outbound stream will not progress if the `AeronSource` at the other end is slower and the buffers have been filled up.
>   If messages are sent at a higher rate than what can be consumed by the receiving node the `SendQueue` will overflow and messages will be dropped. `Aeron` itself has large buffers to be able to handle bursts of messages.
>
> The same thing will happen in the case of a network partition. When the Aeron buffers are full messages will be dropped by the SendQueue.
>
> In the inbound stream the messages are in the end dispatched to the recipient actor. That is an ordinary actor tell that will enqueue the message in the actor’s mailbox. **That is where the back-pressure ends on the receiving side. If the actor is slower than the incoming message rate the mailbox will fill up as usual**.
>
> Bottom line, **flow control for actor messages must be implemented at the application level. Artery does not change that fact**.